# Вебсервис и его задачи

Tags: rest

Кто может объяснить в чем задачи вебсервиса?

Я хочу реализовать вебсервис, который будет предоставлять API для обновления, отображения данных с бд и тд.

Но я не совсем  понимаю в чем вообще задача вебсервиса как такого. Что должен делать вебсервис, а что нет?

Comment: где эксперты?

Comment: чего хотите обновлять? какие бд? Что именно вы хотите? Вы для себя сформулируйте цель, а потом может быть будут более понятные вопросы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответственно Вам заявляю: вебсервис - это штука, которая предоставляет некоторый сервис через Интернет. :)

"предоставлять API для обновления, отображения данных с бд и тд." - отличная задача для вебсервиса.